# Keyboard input and different keys having different response

Tags: c, input, keyboard, console-application

The code below is suppose to get a keyboard input from the user that is either W,A,S or D. When each key is pressed a different message is needed to appear on screen. I am suppose to use an if statement to complete this task. At the moment, the wrong responses are appearing with the wrong inputs.

The current results I get are:

1. Input W =  Character going UP and Character going RIGHT
2. Input S =  Character going DOWN and Character going RIGHT
3. Input A =  Character going LEFT and Character going RIGHT
4. Input D =  Character going RIGHT

The results I want are the following:

1. Input W =  Character going UP
2. Input S =  Character going DOWN
3. Input A =  Character going LEFT
4. Input D =  Character going RIGHT

Thank You

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char keyInput[2];
//Instructions for user to follow 
printf("Controls:   \n");
printf("W = UP:   \n");
printf("A = LEFT    \n");
printf("S = DOWN   \n");
printf("D = RIGHT   \n");
printf("\nWhich direction do you want to go?");

scanf("%s", keyInput);

//choices
if (*keyInput == 'W')
{
    printf("Character going UP\n");
}
else if (*keyInput == 'A')
{
    printf("Character going LEFT\n");
}
else if (*keyInput == 'S')
{
    printf("Character going DOWN\n");
}
else if (*keyInput == 'D');
{
    printf("Character going RIGHT\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about this does not work?  What appears to happen, and how is that not what you wanted to happen?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post. Hopefully with the information you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

> else if (*keyInput == 'D');

should NOT end in a semi-colon